# Lucene .NET result subsets

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I am using Lucene .NET
Let's say I want to only return 50 results starting at result 100, how might I go about that?
I've searched the docs but am not finding anything. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Search queries are much faster on indexed fields as the contents are tokenized, indexed and cached for efficient retrieval. So it doesn't affect the performance. But when you fetch the  additional document  details i.e., extended fields - non indexed fields like descriptions, tags or categories etc., it would incur performance hit. So just read the details for the current paginated results. https://davidsekar.com/c-sharp/indexing-site-contents-using-lucene-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are doing this for the purpose of paging.  The way this is normally done in a Lucene implementation (including Solr) is by simply executing the query normally, but only actually loading the stored data for the results you are interested in.

In a typical paging scenario, this may mean executing the same query multiple times, which may seem like a waste of resources, but with help from the system cache and possibly Lucene's caching it's not so bad.  The benefit is statelessness, which allows you to scale.

Answer (score 5):

Your code should look something like this:

```
TopDocs topDocs = indexSearcher.Search(query, null, 150);
for(int i=100, i<min(topDocs.totalHits,150); i++) {
    Document doc = indexSearcher.doc(topDocs.scoreDocs[i]);

    // Do something with the doc
}
```

Don't use the `Hits` class. It is inefficient and deprecated.